# Suppose $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then $g(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f-\int_{x}^{b}f$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This statement is implicit in the answer to Problem 29 Chapter 13 in Spivak's calculus:

> Suppose $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then
>   $g(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f-\int_{x}^{b}f$ is continuous.

However I can't seem to justify it.  I have no idea how one would apply the epsilon delta definition to prove continuity as I don't know how to deal with the variable inside the limits of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

We only have to show that $h(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t) dt$ is continuous (why ?).

$f$ is bounded, hence there is $M \ge 0$ with $|f(t)| \le M$ for all $t \in [a,b]$. Let $x,y \in [a,b]$ such that $x \le y$

Then: $|h(y)-h(x)|=| \int_{x}^{y}f(t) dt| \le  \int_{x}^{y}|f(t)| dt \le \int_{x}^{y}M dt=M(y-x)=M|y-x|$.

We get the same result if  $x \ge y$ (this is your turn !)

Conclusion: $|h(y)-h(x)| \le M|y-x|$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$.